# How to draw NO2 in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemmacros

It would be nice if you could help me to draw NO2 in LaTeX. The figure should look like the example image.[image: NO2]

On [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics) website is some information about the chemfig/chemmakro package. My code untill now shows a NO2 molecule. Now I just need to add the arrows and nodes (red areas on the original image). How to do that? First of all I will thank @Sigur (he let the chemfig code work) and @ajeh who corrected my angles. And I will thank the German Texwelt (German LaTeX help forum). On that website a user named "Clemens" helped (20 Jul, 05:27) the user "goldsonne23" with the delocated bondings on this [website](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5734/brauche-hilfe-mit-dem-paket-chemfig). So all the Tikz part is just "stolen" from Clemns. Here the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

%delocated bondings
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddbond}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=4pt]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{2pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}
}
\tikzset{
  lddbond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddbond},
  rddbond/.style={decorate,decoration={ddbond,mirror}},
  elmove/.style={->,red,shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt}
}


\begin{document}
%\chemfig{<atom1><bond type>[<angle>,<coeff>,<tikz code>]<atom2>}
\chemfig{O-[:22.85,,,,rddbond]N-[:-22.85,,,,rddbond]O}
\end{document}
```

Anyone who can help? Yours faithfully,
Basilius

Comment: What does 'don't work' mean?

Comment: You need to use `:` for specified angles. Also, removing `draw` works very well: `\chemfig{O=[:67.15,1]N=[:-67.15, 1]O}`

Comment: @Sigur: Does this provide the dashed bond lines (whatever they mean)

Comment: I don't use this package and I don't know how to produce double (solid/dashed) lines. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: When I am trying to compile the MWE using MikTex 2.9, pdflatex crashes with the following error: `starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "d:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: ftp://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 759477432c5e6ba0426dad097cdc7af3
pdflatex.EXE: Unknown archive file size.
pdflatex.EXE: Data: mh

! LaTeX Error: File 'mathtools.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:`

Comment: A double bond is achieved by "=" instead of "-", but have no idea about this combination of "dashed/solid" (electron pair sharing?)

Comment: See Section 6 (pg 27) from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf

Comment: @ajeh, I guess that you have to install the `chemfig` package by hand using MikTeX Package Manager.

Comment: @Sigur Not working for me, but anyhow, I think it should be `\chemfig{O=[:22.85,1]C=[:-22.85, 1]O}`

Comment: @ajeh: partially that's true, but there is only one double bond and the other one is a single one, with some partial positive charge at the Nitrogen atom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cobbled this together using the example in the `chemfig` package (section 12.7).

**Edit:** I also added a plain label (without arrows) next to the bond. I think this looks better because the line with arrows is not quite parallel to the line indicating the bond.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
\setatomsep{5em}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations}

%delocated bondings
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddbond}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=4pt]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{2pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}
}
\tikzset{
  lddbond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddbond},
  rddbond/.style={decorate,decoration={ddbond,mirror}},
  elmove/.style={->,red,shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt}
}

\begin{document}
%\chemfig{<atom1><bond type>[<angle>,<coeff>,<tikz code>]<atom2>}
\chemfig{O-[:22.85,,,,rddbond]N-[:-22.85,,,,rddbond]O}

\newcommand\namebond[4][5pt]{\chemmove{\path(#2)--(#3)
node[midway,sloped,yshift=#1]{\color{red}#4};
}}

\newcommand\bondlengtharrows[4][9pt]{\chemmove{\path(#2)--(#3)
node(p1)[above,at end]{}
node(p2)[above,at start]{}
node[midway,sloped,yshift=#1]{\color{red}#4};
\draw[red,stealth-stealth](p1)--(p2);
}}

\newcommand\arcbetweennodes[3]{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}% 
\let#3\pgfmathresult}

\newcommand\arclabel[6][red,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]{%
\chemmove{%
\arcbetweennodes{#4}{#3}\anglestart \arcbetweennodes{#4}{#5}\angleend \draw[#1]([shift=(\anglestart:#2)]#4)arc(\anglestart:\angleend:#2); \pgfmathparse{(\anglestart+\angleend)/2}\let\anglestart\pgfmathresult \node[shift=(\anglestart:#2+1pt)#4,anchor=\anglestart+180,rotate=\anglestart+90,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(#4){\color{red}#6};}}

\chemfig[scale=2]{@{1}O-[:22.85,,,,rddbond]@{2}N-[:-22.85,,,,rddbond]@{3}O}
\namebond{1}{2}{\footnotesize\SI{119.7}{\pico\meter}}
\bondlengtharrows{2}{3}{\footnotesize\SI{119.7}{\pico\meter}}
\arclabel{5mm}{1}{2}{3}{\footnotesize104.45\si\degree}
\end{document}
```